# Conftest discovery with tests as part of application code

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-fixtures, conftest

I'm using pytest and decided to go with [Tests as part of application code](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#tests-as-part-of-application-code) pattern.
Everything works fine besides conftest discovery.

I have the following structure:

```
module_a/
    a.py
    __tests__/
      conftest.py
      test_a.py
    submodule/
        b.py
        __tests__/
            test_b.py
```

In `conftest.py` under `module_a/__tests__` I define fixtures that I want to be able to use in `module_a/submodule/__tests__`, but it doesn't discover that.
If I move the `conftest.py` to `module_a` (not inside `__tests__`), it works, but I dont want to define it outside of the `__tests__` directory.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Per [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/fixtures.html#conftest-py-sharing-fixtures-across-multiple-files), `conftest.py` relates only to subfolders, and not to folders in other locations. You can create the submodule tests under the main `__tests__` folder.